# How do I "clone" a VB6 form

Tags: vb6

I have opened a form, then clicked File-Save Form As, and given it a new name.  But this just renames the existing form.  I want to keep the existing form, but also have a copy with a different name.

Comment: You do know that you can have multiple windows open at runtime, all based on the same design-time form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6 does keep the original form -- on disk -- it just doesn't keep it in the project, so this should do it:

1. If you've made changes to the open file, you may want to save it in its *current place*, as this won't happen automatically when you save as.
2. Save the form as its new file name.
3. Also change the name of the form in the Properties window to match the new file name.
4. Do `Project -> Add Form -> Existing` and re-add the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't had a running VB6 environment for almost a decade, but I *think* that all you have to do is to make a copy (from Windows Explorer or DOS command line) of your form's .FRM and .FRX files, save them with your new intended form name (the .FRM and .FRX must have the same name), and then use "Add Existing Form" in your Project menu to add it to your project.

Comment: I think for this to work, you'd also need to open the .FRM file in Notepad and search & replace all the references to data in the original .FRX file.